# Am I allowed to give users the option to hide iAds in my app?

Tags: ios, iad

I'd like to display iAds in my app to help cover the cost of the yearly developer program fee, but I'd also like to give the users the option to hide the ads in the interest of openness, as the app is mainly serving up Creative Commons data ([CC BY 4.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) - commercial use permitted).

I was unable to find in Apple's documentation whether this is permitted or not – I may just be overlooking it. If anyone has dealt with this or can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. (And as always if this question is inappropriate for SO, feel free to mark it for removal or transfer.)

Comment: Lots of apps offer ad removal as an in-app purchase, so it's probably fine to offer it for free. Note that [“Apps that contain empty iAd banners will be rejected”](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#advertising) (§7.2) so you must make sure you don't just leave empty space where the ad was. Anyway, yes, this is off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple App Store policy, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are allowed to give users the option to hide iAds in your app.
Try

```
bannerView.hidden=YES
```